# Merging Errors: Attribute meta-data requires a placeholder substitution but no value is provided. BazelFaceMesh.app main manifest (this file)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, bazel, mediapipe

I am migrating the Mediapipe face mesh app from Bazel to Gradle, but when building the app it gives me the following error:

```
Merging Errors:
Error: Attribute meta-data#cameraFacingFront@value at AndroidManifest.xml:38:53-89 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <cameraFacingFront> is provided. BazelFaceMesh.app main manifest (this file), line 37
Error: Attribute meta-data#binaryGraphName@value at AndroidManifest.xml:39:51-85 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <binaryGraphName> is provided. BazelFaceMesh.app main manifest (this file), line 38 
Error: Attribute meta-data#inputVideoStreamName@value at AndroidManifest.xml:40:56-95 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <inputVideoStreamName> is provided. BazelFaceMesh.app main manifest (this file), line 39 
Error: Attribute meta-data#outputVideoStreamName@value at AndroidManifest.xml:41:57-97 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <outputVideoStreamName> is provided. BazelFaceMesh.app main manifest (this file), line 40 
Error: Attribute meta-data#flipFramesVertically@value at AndroidManifest.xml:42:56-95 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <flipFramesVertically> is provided. BazelFaceMesh.app main manifest (this file), line 41 
Error: Attribute meta-data#converterNumBuffers@value at AndroidManifest.xml:43:55-93 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <converterNumBuffers> is provided. BazelFaceMesh.app main manifest (this file), line 42 
Error: Validation failed, exiting BazelFaceMesh.app main manifest (this file)
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:** (the errors are occurring in the `<meta-data>` elements)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.bazelfacemesh">


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="27" />

    <!-- For using the camera -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <!-- For profiling -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Blink to Speak"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BazelFaceMesh">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <meta-data android:name="cameraFacingFront" android:value="${cameraFacingFront}"/>
        <meta-data android:name="binaryGraphName" android:value="${binaryGraphName}"/>
        <meta-data android:name="inputVideoStreamName" android:value="${inputVideoStreamName}"/>
        <meta-data android:name="outputVideoStreamName" android:value="${outputVideoStreamName}"/>
        <meta-data android:name="flipFramesVertically" android:value="${flipFramesVertically}"/>
        <meta-data android:name="converterNumBuffers" android:value="${converterNumBuffers}"/>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle (of the app)** :

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
compileSdk 32

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.bazelfacemesh"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        assets {
            srcDirs 'src\\main\\assets'
        }
    }
}
}
dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'


implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
// MediaPipe deps
implementation 'com.google.flogger:flogger:latest.release'
implementation 'com.google.flogger:flogger-system-backend:latest.release'
implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:latest.release'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.19.1'
// CameraX core library
def camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta10"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:$camerax_version"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
// AutoValue
def auto_value_version = "1.8.1"
implementation "com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:$auto_value_version"
annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:$auto_value_version"
}
```

I had tried setting manifestPlaceholders in build.gradle, but it made no effect.

I tried following [Mediapipe Android Archive](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/android_archive_library.html) documentation step by step, but even here I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Placeholders in the manifest like `${cameraFacingFront}` are filled in with values from the `manifest_values` attribute of `android_binary`, see:
https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/docs/getting_started/hello_world_android.md

E.g.:

```
android_binary(
    name = "app",
    ...
    manifest_values = {
        "applicationId": "com.google.mediapipe.apps.basic",
        "appName": "Hello World",
        "mainActivity": ".MainActivity",
        "cameraFacingFront": "False",
    },
)
```